# Inequality with condition $x+y+z=xy+yz+zx$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, sum-of-squares-method

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x+y+z=xy+yz+zx$, prove that
$$
\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{y}{y^2+1}+\frac{z}{z^2+1}\ge-\frac{1}{2}
$$
My approach:

After slight manipulation the inequality is equivalent to:
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}\ge 2
$$
Now, applying CS is legitimate and it reduces the inequality to proving:
$$
s^2-10s-3\le0
$$
with $s=x+y+z=xy+yz+zx$, but I'm not quite sure if this is still true. Could anybody give me a hint in the right direction? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that equality is when $(x, y, z)$ is some permutation of $(-1, -1, 1)$, so if you're using CS (or any other inequality to prove this) you should ensure the equality condition is maintained.  In this case your usage of CS violates this, so the approach is futile.

Comment: Ok thanks for this piece of advice. But then how to approach such an inequality? Should I, due to symmetry, assume $x\ge y\ge z$ to reduce the set of equality triples to $(1,-1,-1)$? But then, how to argue with that assymetry? Through smoothing?

Comment: Smoothing could work - I haven't tried it though.  The constraint is not an easy one, which is why I eliminated it in the answer posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to use CS to solve the inequality.  First, we re-write what we want to prove as
$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{y^2+1} \ge 2-\frac{(z+1)^2}{z^2+1} = \frac{(z-1)^2}{z^2+1}$$

Now the constraint gives $z = \dfrac{x+y-xy}{x+y-1}$.  Using this, we need to only show
$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{y^2+1} \ge \frac{(xy-1)^2}{(x+y-xy)^2+(x+y-1)^2}$$

Using CS on the LHS, we have
$$\left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{y^2+1}\right)\left((x^2+1)(y-1)^2+(y^2+1)(x-1)^2 \right) \ge \left((x+1)(y-1)+(y+1)(x-1) \right)^2=4(xy-1)^2$$

Thus it is sufficient to show
$$4(x+y-xy)^2+4(x+y-1)^2 \ge (x^2+1)(y-1)^2+(y^2+1)(x-1)^2$$
which reduces to showing that the following quadratic (in say $x$) is non-negative:
$$(y^2-3y+3)x^2 - (3 y^2-8 y+3)x + (3y^2-3y+1) \ge 0$$
which is easy to show as its discriminant, $-3(y^2-1)^2$ is never positive.

Answer (score 1):

It's just $$(x-yz)^2+(y-zx)^2+(z-xy)^2+(x+y+z+1)^2+(x+y+z+xyz)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)$

Hint 2: this is a quadratic equation which places constraints on $x+y+z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: I thought of that, but does it really help?

Comment: See edit (filling up required characters here)

Comment: Still don't get it.